# Plot velocity and acceleration in Matlab\Octave knowing that $v(t)=\frac{t}{t^2+1}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, computational-physics, software

An object of mass $m$ is observed moving along a straight line parallel to the $Ox$ axis. The scalar component of the object's velocity is given as a function of time by $\frac{t}{(t^2+1)}$, where t is the time. I am required to represent the velocity and the acceleration for $t\in[0,5]$. I did the following things:

1. I observed that $v$=$|\vec{v(t)}|$=$\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2+z'(t)^2}$ and $a$=$|\vec{a(t)}|$=$\sqrt{x''(t)^2+y''(t)^2+z''(t)^2}$. However I don`t know how should I use this information as I am not given a parametric form.
2. For a fixed point $O$, if I name my point $M$, then $\vec{r(t)}=\vec{OM}$ and $\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$=$\vec{v}$. Integrating $\frac{t}{(t^2+1)}$ I obtain $\frac{ln(t^2+1)}{2}$. I see no link beetween this information and the one I am given, that the object moves along a straight line parallel to $Ox$.
3. I could represent the velocity in Matlab in a system of axis formed by time and the velocity itself as a function of time. However, I am required to represent the velocity and acceleration in $Oxy$ and $Oxyz$. I can t use the $quiver$ function as I don`t know how to parametrise the velocity.

These being said, I would appreciate a helping hand.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is purely a math - to -code  programming question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something, but this seems entirely straightforward and you are overcomplicating things. If the object moves parallel to the $Ox$ axis then it is a one-dimensional movement, so you can ignore all but the $x$ component.

The scalar velocity is then also the velocity along the $x$-axis, $|v|=v_x =t/(t^2+1)$. The acceleration is just the time derivative of that. So you need to plot $t/(t^2+1)$ and $\frac{d}{dt} (t/(t^2+1))$.

Comment: Ok, I see, but why is $|v|$=$\frac{1}{t^2+1}$? Shouldn`t it be $\frac{t}{1+t^2}$?

Comment: Yes that is a typo, I will correct. Can you accept the answer?

Comment: Yes, it is a good one. Thank you very much!